# Lock app related images from getting accessed from gallery

Tags: android

I have my Android app click photographs and access them within the app. This works fine

But when the photo is clicked they become accessible in the gallery (default photo viewing app of Android). They can be viewed, edited and even deleted from gallery.

I want MY app only to have rights on the photos clicked by it because I don't upload them to server as soon as they are clicked. App waits for wifi to upload them. There will be data integrity issues if the file is updated outside my application when it starts uploading (especially if it is deleted)

I am sure there would be a way to achieve this because Facebook app for Android's images are not available in the gallery unless you explicitly save them.

The question is how to achieve this.

Comment: you can change file type of your images in their names and default apps can not recognize them as images . something like "picture.gggg" or you can save your images in local sqlite db as blob objects and use them whenever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a blank `.nomedia` file in the directory containing your pictures. This will deny Gallery app from scanning that directory.

But please note that this is a quick-fix and if you want to **fully** protect your files, I'd suggest to use a private storage directory on the external storage by using [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

> I have my Android app click photographs and access them within the app

You have not explained how you are doing this.

> I want MY app only to have rights on the photos clicked by it because I don't upload them to server as soon as they are clicked.

Then put the photos on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), not external storage.

If you are taking the pictures yourself using the camera APIs, this is just a matter of where you write the image data.

If you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, move the photo from external storage to internal storage after the photo is taken. Note, though, that the camera app the user chose for handling your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request may have a separate copy of the photo elsewhere, and that copy might get picked up by `MediaStore`.

> Lock app related images from getting accessed from gallery

From your description, a gallery-type app is not your problem. *Any* app is your problem. While a `.nomedia`-type solution may work for keeping your image out of gallery-type apps, if the photo is on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), other apps can still get to it (e.g., file managers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private storage directory on the external storage by calling the `Context` method `getExternalFilesDir()`. You can refer to Android documentation here on [Saving files that are app-private](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles).